# How do I create a library where the linker only links functions used by my program?

Tags: c, gcc, microcontroller, avr, avr-gcc

I am compiling an application program for an **8-bit AVR micro-controller *(AVR-GCC)***. To reduce the flash memory usage in a micro-controller it is essential that the **linker only links functions which are used by the application code**. I am writing my own library and I came across the following statement.

"Write one function per code module. This will compile to one function per object module" - Source: http://nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/library.html

What does this mean? **How do I create separate object files for each of my functions?** Right now I only have one .h file and a .c file in my library.

Comment: You write one .c file for each function. But modern linkers are able to perform "function level linking" (google that) anyway, so you don't need to
"Write one function per code module".

Comment: sometimes creating a library of objects the toolchain will then only pull what it needs and sometimes linking objects not in a library it takes everything.  But this is very much toolchain and possibly version specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

"One function per code module" means one function per C source file. That will give you one object file per function.

This seems awkward, the typical way to do this when using GCC is [as described here](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2003-08/msg00128.html):

1. Compile with the `-fdata-sections -ffunction-sections` options, that tell GCC to put data and functions in separate sections. Sections are just a concept in the object files, basically a stand-alone region. A single object file can contain many sections.
2. Then link with `--gc-sections`, telling the linker to garbage-collect unused sections. This will remove dead code.

Comment: So I have to write one function in each c file and have a single header file for all those c files?

Comment: Not with the way I recommended, no.

Comment: FYI, if you add `-Wl,--print-gc-sections` to the `-Wl,--gc-sections`, the linker will print all sections it throws out. That can be useful to get an idea of what it actually does.